# Getting a very basic aggregate to work

Tags: r

I have been using ddply for aggregating, but it's way too slow for the dataset I currently have. (It takes several minutes.) I would like to get `aggregate` to work, but I'm having trouble getting it to work at a basic level.

Here's something I'm currently trying:

```
v1 <- c("A", "A", "B", "B")
v2 <- c(1:4)
df <- data.frame(v1, v2, stringsAsFactors = F)

agg <- aggregate(df, by = list(v1), sum)
```

Here's the error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

I'm confused about when to use the data frame as the first argument of `aggregate` and when to use it in the `data` argument. Also, what do `~` and `.` mean when used in the first argument?

Comment: `aggregate(v2~v1, df, sum)` would work, but if `ddply` is slow, then `aggregate` would be slower too.

Comment: Why not switch over to "data.table" or "dplyr" if speed is your concern?

Comment: Yes, I'm interested learning "data.table" and "dplyer" but there is a learning curve. I have also read a number of web pages about aggregating in R, but I though that something as basic as grouping data should be straightforward. That's why I wanted to find the most basic way of doing it.

Comment: For something like this, both of those approaches would have a very minimal learning curve.

Comment: @akrun, which of the class methods for `aggregate` is that? It doesn't look like the data frame method as shown in the usual "mtcars" example: http://www.statmethods.net/management/aggregate.html

Comment: @KevinM It is the formula method.  From `?aggregate` `## S3 method for class 'formula'
     aggregate(formula, data, FUN, ...,
               subset, na.action = na.omit)`

Comment: Why does the following work but my example doesn't? `attach(mtcars)
aggdata <-aggregate(mtcars, by=list(cyl,vs), 
  FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: I think it may have to do with the `class`.  All the columns in `mtcars` are numeric class, while your example data have mixed class.  Also, it is not a good practise to `attach` the dataset.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I just got the aggregation to work with `data.table`, and it runs quickly and smoothly.

Comment: Is there are solution that uses the "S3 method for class 'data.frame'" as defined in the documentation?
`aggregate(x, by, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE)`